# Button with tag "input button" and "a" is not on the same line

Tags: css

I'm here again asking :)

I am needing to have 2 types of buttons, one using "input button" and another using the tag "a" link.

But when trying to do this, "button" using the tag "a" is lower than the others, and I'm not able to make it stay in the same line of the other buttons.

I put the example in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/RLgEj/

```
<br><br><br>
<input name="btnSubmit" class="botao salvar" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="btnSubmit" class="botao excluir" type="submit" value="Excluir" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="btnSubmit" class="botao voltar" type="submit" value="Voltar" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="botao voltar" href="/Produto/Index">Voltar&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

tks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.botao {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.botao {
    padding-top: 7px;
    height: 24px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RLgEj/6/

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
<body style="line-height:30px;">
```

**See DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/RLgEj/5/

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css (last rule):

```
.botao {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:6px;
  border:1px solid #87a5b6;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#000;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-left:32px;
  padding-right :16px;
  text-decoration:none;    
  cursor:pointer;   
  height:32px;
  line-height: 32px;/* this is the magic */
}
```

i updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/RLgEj/)